# Upgrade Windows XP 32-bit to 64-bit using repair (e.g. in-place upgrade)

Tags: windows-xp, 32bit-64bit

I have a user with a Mac + VMware Fusion with a 32-bit Windows XP virtual machine. He needs a 64-bit OS for a project he is working on with the development team. It appears that the upgrade process to Windows 7 will most likely result in a clean install. I would like to avoid that as much as possible because he required a couple days worth of hand holding to get his current environment up and running, and that leads me to my question.

Can I use a Windows XP Pro 64-bit installation disk to run a repair install on his Windows XP Pro 32-bit VM, so that all settings are mostly retained? I know it's a long shot, but I'm hoping someone has a good answer for me. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't upgrade from a 32bit Windows OS to a 64bit Windows OS.

Comment: http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/32-bit-and-64-bit-Windows-frequently-asked-questions#

Comment: @pk: Did you actually read the information at the link you posted? You can't upgrade a 32bit Windows OS to a 64bit Windows OS.

Comment: @joeqwerty: easy bud...  I just posted the link to back you up.  If you're wondering where the upvote came from on your response, that was me too.  I simply though he might like to see some official documentation.

Comment: @pk: My apologies. I assumed that you were inferring that the link purported to say that you could upgrade. I'll step away from the keyboard now...

Comment: As stated, you cannot upgrade 32 to 64 bit.  You MIGHT be able to migrate user files and settings with a tool like the User State Migration Tool or Windows Easy Transfer.  But other than that I would consider any attempt to do something like this that is not supported in a business environment is a bad idea as unexpected problems can occur.

Answer (score 0):

In short: No.

None of the current 32 bit applications would work correctly, because Windows secludes most of them in SysWOW64 at installation time.

It's theoretically possible, but not without a massive amount of time investment.